# VHDL: FSM with multiple state types

Tags: vhdl, fsm

We are trying to build a controller for a robot that is able to do two different tasks, searching for a line and tracking a line. (We make use of three lightresistors to detect the line drawn on the ground.) The idea was to create an fsm moore machine, that however uses instead of only one type of state update several. The reason for that is that each state is required to go to a reset state after a 20 ms in order to update other components that otherwise wont work. In order to go back to the original state, we make use of an additional state sequence that is used as an input in order for the moore machine to know where to return. (It might help to know that reducing the code to only tracking the line works perfectly, also implemented in real life.)

The strange thing is that the code simulated on ModelSim works flawlessly, everything is connected, etc., yet when implementing it, we get a dozen of warnings mentioning the existence of latches (regarding the two other state sequences new_eureka and new_StoredValue), which totally screws up our operations. Yet looking at the code we cant really find why these latches are being produced. 
How can we avoid these latches from appearing?

Below the code and the warnings produced through Quartus software.

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity LineFinder is
  port (    clk     : in    std_logic;
        reset       : in    std_logic;
        count_out   : in    std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
      sensor_l_out  : in    std_logic;
        sensor_m_out    : in    std_logic;
        sensor_r_out    : in    std_logic;

        pwm_l_reset : out   std_logic;
        pwm_l_direction : out std_logic;
        pwm_r_reset : out   std_logic;
        pwm_r_direction : out std_logic;    

        count_reset: out std_logic  
    );
end entity LineFinder;


architecture behaviour of LineFinder is

  component input_buffer is
    port (  clk     : in    std_logic;

        sensor_l_in : in    std_logic;
        sensor_m_in : in    std_logic;
        sensor_r_in : in    std_logic;

        sensor_l_out    : out   std_logic;
        sensor_m_out    : out   std_logic;
        sensor_r_out    : out   std_logic
    );
  end component input_buffer;

  type line_state is (reset_state, 
                      FindLine_state, 
                      PassLine_state, 
                      CorrectLeft_state, 
                      CorrectRight_state, 
                      wbw_state,

                      bbb_state,
                      bbw_state, 
                      bwb_state, 
                      bww_state, 
                      wbb_state,  
                      wwb_state, 
                      www_state);                   
  signal state , new_state: line_state ;

  type eureka_state is (FindingLine, 
            PassingLine, 
            CorrectingRight, 
            CorrectingLeft,  
            TrackingLine);
  signal eureka, new_eureka: eureka_state;

  signal StoredValue, new_StoredValue: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000";

  constant period: std_logic_vector(19 downto 0) := std_logic_vector (to_unsigned(1000000, 20));

  begin


    Process1: process (clk, reset)
      begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
          if (reset ='1') then
            state <= FindLine_state;
            eureka <= FindingLine;
        StoredValue <= "000";
          else
          state <= new_state;
          eureka <= new_eureka;
      StoredValue <= new_StoredValue;
        end if;
      end if;
      end process;

      --Finding Line process
      Process2: process (state, eureka, StoredValue, count_out, sensor_l_out, sensor_m_out, sensor_r_out)
        begin
          if ((not((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '0'))) and (eureka = PassingLine)) then
            new_StoredValue <= sensor_r_out & sensor_m_out & sensor_l_out;
          end if;

          case state is
          when FindLine_state =>
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= FindingLine;
            elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
              new_state <= FindLine_state;
              new_eureka <= FindingLine;
            elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
              new_state <= wbw_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= PassLine_state;
              new_eureka <= PassingLine;
            end if;

          when PassLine_state =>
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= PassingLine;
            elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
              if ((StoredValue = "001") or (StoredValue = "011")) then 
                  new_state <= CorrectRight_state;
                  new_eureka <= CorrectingRight;
              else
                  new_state <= CorrectLeft_state;
                  new_eureka <= CorrectingLeft;
              end if;
            else 
              new_state <= PassLine_state;
              new_eureka <= PassingLine;
            end if;


          when CorrectRight_state =>
            pwm_l_reset <= '0'; --making sharp turn to right
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '1'; 
            count_reset <= '0';            
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= CorrectingRight;
            elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
              new_state <= wbw_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= CorrectRight_state;
              new_eureka <= CorrectingRight;
            end if;

          when CorrectLeft_state => 
            pwm_l_reset <= '0'; --making sharp turn to left
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '0';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= CorrectingLeft;
            elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
              new_state <= wbw_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= CorrectLeft_state;
              new_eureka <= CorrectingLeft;
            end if;

          when wbw_state =>     --aka LineFoundState   
            -- go to LineTracker process!
            -- forward trigger
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';      
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= wbw_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;

          when reset_state => 
            pwm_l_reset <= '1';
            pwm_r_reset <= '1';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '1';
            count_reset <= '1';
            if (not(eureka = TrackingLine)) then
              if (eureka = FindingLine) then
                new_state <= FindLine_state;
                new_eureka <= FindingLine;
              elsif (eureka = PassingLine) then
                new_state <= PassLine_state;
                new_eureka <= PassingLine;
              elsif (eureka = CorrectingRight) then
                new_state <= CorrectRight_state;
                new_eureka <= CorrectingRight;
              elsif (eureka = CorrectingLeft) then
                new_state <= CorrectLeft_state;
                new_eureka <= CorrectingLeft;
              else
                new_state <= FindLine_state;  --do we need this?
                new_eureka <= FindingLine;
              end if;
            else
              --The other reset process
              if ((sensor_l_out = '1') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '1')) then
                new_state <= bbb_state;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '1') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
                new_state <= bbw_state;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '1') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '1')) then
                new_state <= bwb_state;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '1') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
                new_state <= bww_state;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '1')) then
                new_state <= wbb_state;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
                new_state <= wbw_state;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '1')) then
                new_state <= wwb_state;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
                new_state <= www_state;             
              else
                new_state <= reset_state;
              end if;
            end if;



            when bbb_state => -- forward
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';      
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= bbb_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when bbw_state => -- right turn
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '1';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';            
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;              
            else
              new_state <= bbw_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when bwb_state => -- forward trigger
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= bwb_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when bww_state => -- right sharp turn
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '1'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= bww_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when wbb_state => -- left turn
            pwm_l_reset <= '1';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= wbb_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when wwb_state => -- left sharp turn
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '0';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= wwb_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when www_state => -- forward search
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= FindingLine;
            else
              new_state <= www_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


      end case;
    end process;


  end architecture behaviour;
```

The warnings:

```
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning (10631): VHDL Process Statement warning at LineFinder.vhdl(84): inferring latch(es) for signal or variable "new_StoredValue", which holds its previous value in one or more paths through the process
Warning (10631): VHDL Process Statement warning at LineFinder.vhdl(84): inferring latch(es) for signal or variable "new_eureka", which holds its previous value in one or more paths through the process
Warning (13012): Latch LineFinder:lbl1|new_eureka.TrackingLine_445 has unsafe behavior
    Warning (13013): Ports D and ENA on the latch are fed by the same signal LineFinder:lbl1|state.reset_state
Warning (13012): Latch LineFinder:lbl1|new_eureka.CorrectingRight_463 has unsafe behavior
    Warning (13013): Ports D and ENA on the latch are fed by the same signal LineFinder:lbl1|state.reset_state
Warning (13012): Latch LineFinder:lbl1|new_StoredValue[0] has unsafe behavior
    Warning (13013): Ports D and ENA on the latch are fed by the same signal input_buffer:lbl0|ThreeBitRegister:lbl1|data_out[2]
Warning (13012): Latch LineFinder:lbl1|new_StoredValue[2] has unsafe behavior
    Warning (13013): Ports D and ENA on the latch are fed by the same signal input_buffer:lbl0|ThreeBitRegister:lbl1|data_out[0]
Warning (13012): Latch LineFinder:lbl1|new_eureka.PassingLine_472 has unsafe behavior
    Warning (13013): Ports D and ENA on the latch are fed by the same signal LineFinder:lbl1|state.reset_state
Warning (13012): Latch LineFinder:lbl1|new_eureka.FindingLine_481 has unsafe behavior
    Warning (13013): Ports D and ENA on the latch are fed by the same signal LineFinder:lbl1|state.reset_state
Warning (13012): Latch LineFinder:lbl1|new_eureka.CorrectingLeft_454 has unsafe behavior
    Warning (13013): Ports D and ENA on the latch are fed by the same signal LineFinder:lbl1|state.reset_state
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning (292013): Feature LogicLock is only available with a valid subscription license. You can purchase a software subscription to gain full access to this feature.
Warning (15714): Some pins have incomplete I/O assignments. Refer to the I/O Assignment Warnings report for details
Warning (335093): TimeQuest Timing Analyzer is analyzing 7 combinational loops as latches. For more details, run the Check Timing command in the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer or view the "User-Specified and Inferred Latches" table in the Analysis & Synthesis report.
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning (335093): TimeQuest Timing Analyzer is analyzing 7 combinational loops as latches. For more details, run the Check Timing command in the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer or view the "User-Specified and Inferred Latches" table in the Analysis & Synthesis report.
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
Warning (10905): Generated the EDA functional simulation netlist because it is the only supported netlist type for this device.
```

Comment: All your latches are caused by the combinatorial process `process2`. Example1 : `new_StoredValue` isn't driven in a else statement at the beginning of the process. Example 2 : same for  `new_eureka` in the `reset_state` state. You need to specify the status of all your signals in all of the possible states. Otherwise, to avoid this you may use only clocked processes.

Comment: Bear in mind that you're working with hardware, not software. You aren't necessarily required to go to a reset state to do other things, you can just do them in parallel. That's the whole advantage of custom hardware for digital logic.

Comment: True QuantumRipple, but in this case the motors that we have only work if the system is regularly reset, unless you transfer the intelligence of the controller to the motors. But that is making a mess of things.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as mentioned in the comment section by A. Kieffer, I had not specified in all cases (especially in the reset state) what the new_StoredValue or the new_eureka was. This decision making was then introduced by latches, offering unwanted behaviour.

The corrected code below succeeds in avoiding the creation of the latches.

```
library IEEE;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity LineFinder is
  port (    clk     : in    std_logic;
        reset       : in    std_logic;
        count_out   : in    std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
      sensor_l_out  : in    std_logic;
        sensor_m_out    : in    std_logic;
        sensor_r_out    : in    std_logic;

        pwm_l_reset : out   std_logic;
        pwm_l_direction : out std_logic;
        pwm_r_reset : out   std_logic;
        pwm_r_direction : out std_logic;    

        count_reset: out std_logic  
    );
end entity LineFinder;


architecture behaviour of LineFinder is

  component input_buffer is
    port (  clk     : in    std_logic;

        sensor_l_in : in    std_logic;
        sensor_m_in : in    std_logic;
        sensor_r_in : in    std_logic;

        sensor_l_out    : out   std_logic;
        sensor_m_out    : out   std_logic;
        sensor_r_out    : out   std_logic
    );
  end component input_buffer;

  type line_state is (reset_state, 
                      FindLine_state, 
                      PassLine_state, 
                      CorrectLeft_state, 
                      CorrectRight_state, 
                      wbw_state,

                      bbb_state,
                      bbw_state, 
                      bwb_state, 
                      bww_state, 
                      wbb_state,  
                      wwb_state, 
                      www_state);                   
  signal state , new_state: line_state ;

  type eureka_state is (FindingLine, 
            PassingLine, 
            CorrectingRight, 
            CorrectingLeft,  
            TrackingLine);
  signal eureka, new_eureka: eureka_state;

  signal StoredValue, new_StoredValue: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000";

  constant period: std_logic_vector(19 downto 0) := std_logic_vector (to_unsigned(1000000, 20));

  begin


    Process1: process (clk, reset)
      begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
          if (reset ='1') then
            state <= FindLine_state;
            eureka <= FindingLine;
        StoredValue <= "000";
          else
          state <= new_state;
          eureka <= new_eureka;
      StoredValue <= new_StoredValue;
        end if;
      end if;
      end process;

      --Finding Line process
      Process2: process (state, eureka, StoredValue, count_out, sensor_l_out, sensor_m_out, sensor_r_out)
        begin
          if ((not((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '0'))) and (eureka = PassingLine)) then
            new_StoredValue <= sensor_r_out & sensor_m_out & sensor_l_out;
      else
        new_StoredValue <= StoredValue;
          end if;

          case state is
          when FindLine_state =>
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= FindingLine;
            elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
              new_state <= FindLine_state;
              new_eureka <= FindingLine;
            elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
              new_state <= wbw_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= PassLine_state;
              new_eureka <= PassingLine;
            end if;

          when PassLine_state =>
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= PassingLine;
            elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
              if ((StoredValue = "001") or (StoredValue = "011")) then 
                  new_state <= CorrectRight_state;
                  new_eureka <= CorrectingRight;
              else
                  new_state <= CorrectLeft_state;
                  new_eureka <= CorrectingLeft;
              end if;
            else 
              new_state <= PassLine_state;
              new_eureka <= PassingLine;
            end if;


          when CorrectRight_state =>
            pwm_l_reset <= '0'; --making sharp turn to right
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '1'; 
            count_reset <= '0';            
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= CorrectingRight;
            elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
              new_state <= wbw_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= CorrectRight_state;
              new_eureka <= CorrectingRight;
            end if;

          when CorrectLeft_state => 
            pwm_l_reset <= '0'; --making sharp turn to left
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '0';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= CorrectingLeft;
            elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
              new_state <= wbw_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= CorrectLeft_state;
              new_eureka <= CorrectingLeft;
            end if;

          when wbw_state =>     --aka LineFoundState   
            -- go to LineTracker process!
            -- forward trigger
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';      
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= wbw_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;

          when reset_state => 
            pwm_l_reset <= '1';
            pwm_r_reset <= '1';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '1';
            count_reset <= '1';
            if (not(eureka = TrackingLine)) then
              if (eureka = FindingLine) then
                new_state <= FindLine_state;
                new_eureka <= FindingLine;
              elsif (eureka = PassingLine) then
                new_state <= PassLine_state;
                new_eureka <= PassingLine;
              elsif (eureka = CorrectingRight) then
                new_state <= CorrectRight_state;
                new_eureka <= CorrectingRight;
              elsif (eureka = CorrectingLeft) then
                new_state <= CorrectLeft_state;
                new_eureka <= CorrectingLeft;
              else
                new_state <= FindLine_state;  --do we need this?
                new_eureka <= FindingLine;
              end if;
            else
              --The other reset process
              if ((sensor_l_out = '1') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '1')) then
                new_state <= bbb_state;
                new_eureka <= eureka;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '1') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
                new_state <= bbw_state;
                new_eureka <= eureka;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '1') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '1')) then
                new_state <= bwb_state;
                new_eureka <= eureka;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '1') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
                new_state <= bww_state;
                new_eureka <= eureka;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '1')) then
                new_state <= wbb_state;
                new_eureka <= eureka;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='1') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
                new_state <= wbw_state;
                new_eureka <= eureka;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '1')) then
                new_state <= wwb_state;
                new_eureka <= eureka;
              elsif ((sensor_l_out = '0') and (sensor_m_out ='0') and (sensor_r_out = '0')) then
                new_state <= www_state;  
                new_eureka <= eureka;           
              else
                new_state <= reset_state;
                new_eureka <= eureka;
              end if;
            end if;



            when bbb_state => -- forward
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';      
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= bbb_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when bbw_state => -- right turn
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '1';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';            
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;              
            else
              new_state <= bbw_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when bwb_state => -- forward trigger
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= bwb_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when bww_state => -- right sharp turn
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '1'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= bww_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when wbb_state => -- left turn
            pwm_l_reset <= '1';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= wbb_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when wwb_state => -- left sharp turn
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '0';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            else
              new_state <= wwb_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;


            when www_state => -- forward search
            pwm_l_reset <= '0';
            pwm_r_reset <= '0';
            pwm_l_direction <= '1';
            pwm_r_direction <= '0'; 
            count_reset <= '0';
            if (count_out >= period) then
              new_state <= reset_state;
              new_eureka <= FindingLine;
            else
              new_state <= www_state;
              new_eureka <= TrackingLine;
            end if;

      end case;
    end process;


  end architecture behaviour;
```